# Dataframe get index date from value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df

[image]

and in iteration with print statement,

```
print(df.iloc[i])
```

I am getting value as

[image]

But how to get the index value of it which is a date from df.iloc[i]?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you want to return? 

Do you want to return only the value of the date column instead of the entire row? Row index by default starts at 0 and increments by one going from top to bottom.

Comment: df.iloc[i].name prints 2021-02-10 00:00:00 but I need only 2021-02-10

Comment: ok I think I know what is going on, I wrote an answer below see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.iloc[i].name` should give you the index for that particular row.

Comment: df.iloc[i].name prints 2021-02-10 00:00:00. How to get only date

Comment: Do you mean `df.loc['20-04-28']`?

Comment: @wwnde: df.iloc[i].name prints 2021-02-10 00:00:00 but I need only 2021-02-10

Comment: assuming your dataframe is df, what is the datatype of date column?

run print(df.dtypes)

Comment: date column is index with date obj

Comment: `df.index=df.index.astype(str)` and then `df.iloc[i].name` You are getting back datetime because index as so. Please convert to string

Answer (score 0):

We have to reset the index since can't perform transformations on the index afaik.

New date column looks like datetime object so we have to import it.

The code below would create a new column with only the year-month-day in a new column. You can always drop the old date column later.

```
import datetime as dt
df.reset_index()
df['Y-M-D-Only'] = df['Date'].dt.date
for i in df['Y-M-D-Only']:
    print(i)
```